Question on 'Improved bounds for the sunflower lemma'
I have been reading the paper 'Improved Bounds for the Sunflower Lemma' (Ann. of Math., Vol. 194(3), pp. 795-815), here is my question:
In section 2.3. putting everything together: they define $A(\Delta,\ell)$ and $B(\Delta,\ell)$,

and they bound $A(1/2,\ell)$ and $B(1/2,\ell)$ by Lemma 2.10,

but I totally don't understand:

Why $A(\Delta,\ell)$ and $B(\Delta,\ell)$ can be bounded, I couldn't see that from the definition of $A,B$.
Why $(1/2;\kappa^{-1},\cdots,\kappa^{-w^*})$-spread is also $(1;(\kappa/2)^{-1},\cdots,(\kappa/2)^{-w^*})$-spread, I couldn't make this observation.

Here is Lemma 2.10:

And here are some definitions:
Satisfying set systems:


$\kappa$-spread set systems:


Weight set system, weight profile and $\boldsymbol{s}$-spreadness:


Satisfying weight profile:


Please provide the required definition/context in your post.

Thanks for your advice, I have updated my post

For question 1, they are just working backwards to make sure their parameters satisfy the assumptions in Lemma 2.10. Note that $\Delta = \frac{1}{2}$.
For question 2, we need to unpack the definitions, and do a rescaling of the weight function. Let $\mathbf{s_1} = (\frac{1}{2};\kappa^{-1},\dots,\kappa^{-w^*})$, and $\mathbf{s_2} = (1;\left(\frac{\kappa}{2}\right)^{-1},\dots,\left(\frac{\kappa}{2}\right)^{-w^*})$. If $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathbf{s_1}$-spread, then there exists a weight function $\sigma_1$ such that $(\mathcal{F}, \sigma_1)$ is $\mathbf{s_1}$-spread. By definition, this means
$$
\sigma_1(\mathcal{F})\geq \frac{1}{2},
$$
and for any link $\mathcal{F}_T$ with non-empty $T$
$$
\sigma_1(\mathcal{F}_T)\leq \kappa^{-|T|}.
$$
We want to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathbf{s_2}$-spread, so we have to provide some $\sigma_2$ such that $(\mathcal{F},\sigma_2)$ is $\mathbf{s_2}$-spread. Letting $\sigma_2 = 2\sigma_1$ works. We show that the conditions $(i)$ and $(ii)$ in definition 2.1 are satisfied.
$$
\sigma_2(\mathcal{F}) = 2\sigma_1(\mathcal{F})\geq 1,\tag{$i^*$}
$$
and since $|T|\geq 1$
$$
\sigma_2(\mathcal{F}_T) = 2\sigma_1(\mathcal{F}_T)\leq 2\kappa^{-|T|}\leq 2^{|T|}\kappa^{-|T|}.\tag{$ii^*$}
$$

I still confused about question 1, the authors said ‘we will apply Lemma 2.10 to bound A(1/2, w∗)≤α/2 and B(1/2, w∗)≤β/2’. They apply Lemma 2.10 to make sure s(1/2,w*) is (α/2, β/2)-satisfying, and by definition s(1/2, w*) is ( A(1/2, w*), B(1/2, w*) )-satisfying, but why A, B can be bounded by α/2, β/2? I can't see any relation in this bound.
